# ons-lazy-repeat のメンバーを削除した際に詰め合わされない

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

複数のメンバーを持つリストから任意のメンバー削除した際、
リストのデータは削除されるのですが、空白行として残ってしまいます。
前後を詰め合わせたいのですが、どうすれば良いのでしょうか？

```js
//編集ロジック
function funcRepeat($scope){
    $scope.RepeatDelegate = {
      countItems: function() {
        return table.length; 
      },
      calculateItemHeight: function(index) {
        return 45;
      },
      configureItemScope: function(index, itemScope) {
        itemScope.data = table[index];
        itemScope.id = index;
        },
      destroyItemScope: function(index, itemScope) {
      }
    };
};
//削除ロジック
function Click(obj){
  var id = obj.id; //任意のidを指定
  var node = document.getElementById(id);
  removeElement(node); //データは消えるが空白行が残る
}
```

```html
<ons-list id="list" ng-controller="RepeatController">
 <ons-list-item id="{{id}}" class="list-item"  ons-lazy-repeat="RepeatDelegate">
  //省略
    {{data}}
 </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOMを直接触るのではなく、`ons-lazy-repeat`で表示させようとしているリストデータを更新し、Delegateのrefresh()を呼んでください。
https://onsen.io/v2/docs/angular1/ons-lazy-repeat.html#method-refresh

---

追記
refresh()を呼ぶ必要もなさそうですね。
表示に利用しているリストデータの方を追加/削除などすれば反映されました。

繰り返しますがDOMを触るのは間違いです。データの方を更新してください。

---

ng-clickにクリックされた場合に呼び出す削除処理(onDelete)を記載しています。
$indexでインデックス値を参照することができます。
削除処理にて渡されたインデックス値のデータをtableから削除しています。

```js
//編集ロジック
function funcRepeat($scope){
    $scope.RepeatDelegate = {
      countItems: function() {
        return table.length; 
      },
      calculateItemHeight: function(index) {
        return 45;
      },
      configureItemScope: function(index, itemScope) {
        itemScope.data = table[index];
        itemScope.id = index;
        },
      destroyItemScope: function(index, itemScope) {
      }
    };

    $scope.onDelete = function(index) {
      table.splice(index, 1);
    }
};
```

```html
<ons-list id="list" ng-controller="RepeatController">
 <ons-list-item id="{{id}}" class="list-item"  ons-lazy-repeat="RepeatDelegate" ng-click="onDelete($index)">
  //省略
    {{data}}
 </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```

Comment: ons-lazy-repeat で数100行のデータを随時編集しており、
クリックされた行を削除したいのです。
データ側を更新するというのはどのようなロジックに
なるのでしょうか？
(前出のロジックにRepeatDelegateによる編集部分を追記しました。)

Comment: 回答に追記しました。tableというのがおそらくrepeatで表示させたいリストデータなのかと思います。その表示させたいリストデータを更新することでView側に反映させます。View（DOM）側を触るのはons-lazy-repeatに任せて、ons-lazy-repeatで表示させているデータを更新しています。